# Custom x-scale doesn't reflect the month of the date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a graph where "Jan" is replaced by the year on the x-axis, and the other labels are the abbreviated months.

The code replicates the problem, instead of January, e.g. `"month(data$date) == 1"`, being changed to show the year it is November.

Changing the code to `"month(data$date) == 3"` gives the correct result, but I'd prefer to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
library("tidyverse", "lubridate")
data <- tibble(date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 24), value = 1:24)
ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = value, label = value), hjust = -1) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = ifelse(month(data$date) == 1, "%Y", "%b"))
```

Comment: It's showing the year in place of December, not November. That's because you're making a vector of date labels based on the order dates appear in your data, which is not exactly how they'll be placed on the axis: the extra padding at either end of the axis means the first label by default will be December 1999, not January 2000. Instead, you can write a function to format your dates, and pass to the `labels` argument, not `date_labels`

Comment: See a slightly more complicated version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380587/annotate-first-month-with-year-in-ggplot2), where each year didn't necessarily have data starting at January

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I found that adding "expand = c(0,0)" to the scale_x_date, also gave the result I wanted.  Though, using "labels" is the better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`labels=` can take a function which inputs dates and outputs character string labels so one can be sure that the labels correspond to the dates.  It can be used like this:

```
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value), hjust = -1) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
    labels = function(x) ifelse(month(x) == 1, year(x), months(x, TRUE)))
```

or use formula notation to specify the function:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value), hjust = -1) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
    labels = ~ ifelse(month(.) == 1, year(.), months(., TRUE)))
```

[image: screenshot]